# TCPDF: set default white background of pdf into gray and change the block background to white

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am creating PDF document and the default background color is white. I want to change the color of background to gray and then the all the block which is in my for loop should have background white. Is it possible?

I have tried using few of the answer from stack Overflow and if the block is not breaking to the next page, pages are gray but the moment my block sneaks to the next page, that page would be white.

for the first page, I have this code

```
$pdf->SetFillColor(242,242,242);
$pdf->Rect(0, 0, $pdf->getPageWidth(), $pdf->getPageHeight(), 'DF', "",array(242,242,242));
```

and then when my for loop spins, under the condition

```
if($blockSize > $pagheHeight){
   $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
   $pdf->setPage($page+1,true);
   $pdf->SetFillColor(242,242,242);
   $pdf->Rect(0, 0, $pdf->getPageWidth(), $pdf->getPageHeight(), 'DF', "",array(242,242,242));
}
```

Also, My content on pdf will be text, images and is formed into rectangle shape. How can i give background color of the block?

and if background color is set gray throughout, then if i am applying any border on any `td` element, it won't display.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `Header()` function

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Header() {
        $this->Rect(0, 0, $this->getPageWidth(), $this->getPageHeight(), 'F', array(), array(120));
        TCPDF::Header();
    }
}
```

This way, it'll be applied for all pages and it won't overwrite page header contents.